# Passing collection from backgroundworker DoWork to backgroundworker Completed and perform a foreach

Tags: c#

My goal here is:

- User types full or partial computername into combobox
- button click event starts background worker passing computername to DoWork method
- DoWork method searches ActiveDirectory for computername and passes the collection to WorkerCompleted method
- WorkerCompleted method adds each computername to the combobox items.

My error is at the foreach loop in my backgroundWorker_RunWorkerCompleted method.

- "foreach statement cannot operate on variables of type 'object' because 'object' does not contain a public definition for 'GetEnumerator'"

If I do a MessageBox.Show(results.First().ToString()); in the DoWork method, I can view the first computername in the collection.

If I do a MessageBox.Show(e.Result.ToString()); in the DoWork and WorkerCompleted method, I get this:

- "System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.PrincipalSearchResult`1[System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.Principal]"

Any guidance on this would be greatly appreciated!

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Saves computername entered by user to pass into DoWork method
        string PCName = comboBox1.Text;

        //Start background thread passing computer to the Dowork method
        backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync(PCName);
    }
   
    private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {                 
        using (PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain))
        {
            //Setup Filter
            ComputerPrincipal computer = new ComputerPrincipal(ctx);
            computer.Name = "*" + e.Argument + "*";

            //Search for PC
            PrincipalSearcher ps = new PrincipalSearcher();
            ps.QueryFilter = computer;

            //Get Results
            PrincipalSearchResult<Principal> results = ps.FindAll();
                 
            //results will be passed to RunWorkerCompleted
            e.Result = results;                
        }
    }

    private void backgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        //Add each computername to combobox
        foreach (object PC in e.Result) // <--------------- ERROR HERE!
        {
            comboBox1.Items.Add(PC.ToString());
        }                            
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to cast `e.Result` in Completed handler from `object` to `PrincipalSearchResult<Principal>` in order to iterate through it.

```
private void backgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    //Add each computername to combobox
    PrincipalSearchResult<Principal> results = (PrincipalSearchResult<Principal>)e.Result;
    foreach (Principal PC in results)
    {
        comboBox1.Items.Add(PC.ToString());
    }                            
}
```

Edit:

`PrincipalSearcher` can't be used in Background Worker, because it's uses of COM component that requires Single-threaded Apartment (STA). Background Worker thread runs in multithreaded apartment (MTA). ApartmentState can be set using `Thread.SetApartmentState`, but it must be called before thread starts (so it can't be used to change ApartmentState of BackgroundWorker's working thread).

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Added your code and got the same error as Blau.
An exception of type 'System.InvalidCastException' occurred in System.DirectoryServices.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Unable to cast COM object of type 'System.__ComObject' to interface type 'IDirectorySearch'. This operation failed because the QueryInterface call on the COM component for the interface with IID '{109BA8EC-92F0-11D0-A790-00C04FD8D5A8}' failed due to the following error: No such interface supported (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80004002 (E_NOINTERFACE)).

Comment: That's ugl one.  It happens because `PrincipalSearcher` use COM component and cannot be safely used from Background Worker.

Comment: Shoot! That solves that. Now to look into a work around. I appreciate your help! I would +1 your post but i need more rep.

Comment: Just mark answer as accepted for others to see. Click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.

Answer (score 1):

You should cast the object to IEnumerable or the type that you know it is

```
  var collection = (PrincipalSearchResult<Principal>) e.Result;
  foreach (var PC in collection) 
    {
        comboBox1.Items.Add(PC.ToString());
    }
```

Comment: Added System.Collections,
Added your suggestion, got this error. Reading about IEnumerable now.

exception of type 'System.InvalidCastException' occurred in System.DirectoryServices.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Unable to cast COM object of type 'System.__ComObject' to interface type 'IDirectorySearch'. This operation failed because the QueryInterface call on the COM component for the interface with IID '{109BA8EC-92F0-11D0-A790-00C04FD8D5A8}' failed due to the following error: No such interface supported (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80004002 (E_NOINTERFACE)).

Comment: I don't know why you have to add System.Collections, it's not need for cast... other question is does PrincipalSearchResult implement IEnumerable interface?

Comment: I added it in hopes it would change something haha. I read a little more about IEnum and if i read correctly it's the genric version of Enumerable? Anyways, no it doesn't implemnt the IEnum interface. Still getting the InvalidCast Exception.