# InvalidCastException when using Task return value

Tags: c#, multithreading, active-directory, async-await, task-parallel-library

I have spend almost two days reading async/await tutorials and answers on Stackoverflow and trying to understand asynchronous and parallel execution in C#. Still I can not get it to work with my code.

## What I need

Execute a Active Directory search through PrincipalSearcher asynchronously without blocking the WPF UI.

## Implementation

```
protected async void SearchButtonClick()
{
    Task<PrincipalSearchResult<Principal>> searchTask = Task.Run(() => _activeDirectory.FindGroup(searchText.Text));

    PrincipalSearchResult<Principal> searchResult = await searchTask;

    foreach (var foundGroup in searchResult) /*exception thrown here*/
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

Class of *_activeDirectory*:

```
public PrincipalSearchResult<Principal> FindGroup(String pattern)
{
    ...
    PrincipalSearchResult<Principal> searchResult = searcher.FindAll();
    return searchResult;
}
```

## Problem

- `await` does not seem to wait for the task to complete. `searchTask.IsCompleted` is true after the await line, but it can't be because it takes almost no time to be completed and if I run it synchronously the search takes about 5s.
- An exception if thrown at the beginning of the foreach loop:

> System.InvalidCastException occurred   HResult=-2147467262
>   Message=Unable to cast COM object of type 'System.__ComObject' to
>   interface type 'IDirectorySearch'. This operation failed because the
>   QueryInterface call on the COM component for the interface with IID
>   '{109BA8EC-92F0-11D0-A790-00C04FD8D5A8}' failed due to the following
>   error: No such interface supported (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80004002
>   (E_NOINTERFACE)).   Source=System.DirectoryServices   StackTrace:
>          at System.DirectoryServices.SearchResultCollection.get_SearchObject()
>   InnerException:

## Thoughts

- What I found is that this kind of exception is related to invalid SynchronizationContext but I don't see how this could have happened here. I also printed Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId on several lines of codes and it always returned the same id.
- I also read that async methods should not return `void` but `Task<T>` but I don't think this is relevant here because nobody is using SearchButtonClick() asynchronously. And `Task.Run()`probably does return a Task if that even relevant. The whole subject is still foggy to me.

## Question

- **Why does `await` not wait for the Task to complete?**
- **What is the reason for the exception?**

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18110738/passing-collection-from-backgroundworker-dowork-to-backgroundworker-completed-an

Comment: @Gosha_Fighten I had already tried `PrincipalSearchResult<Principal> searchResult = (PrincipalSearchResult<Principal>) await searchTask;`. This did not solve the problem.

Answer (score 3):

`await` **does** wait for the [`Task`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.aspx) to complete. The only thing you've missed with `async\await` pattern and TPL library is that the `Exception` being thrown **inside** the [`Task`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.aspx) isn't being thrown right in that moment. It's being cached inside the [`Exception`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.exception.aspx) property of the `Task` and is being thrown right after you want to get th result of it.

So the problem is that the code you're running inside the [`Task`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.aspx), can't be run into another thread, as @NineBerry said. You have to create your `AD`-object **inside** the [`Task`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.aspx), something like this:

```
Task<PrincipalSearchResult<Principal>> searchTask = Task.Run(() =>
{
    // this have to be a local variable inside your task
    var _activeDirectory = GET_THE_AD();
    return _activeDirectory.FindGroup(searchText.Text));
}
```

or, may be, you have to create the `searcher` variable each time for your thread.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot use `_activeDirectory` on another thread than where you create the object.

This is based on the way the COM host used inside your object is implemented. Some COM hosts are implemented in a way so that they can be used on multiple threads, some are implemented in a way so that an object can only be used on the same thread where it was created.

You need to change your code to create `_activeDirectory` within the code you execute in `Task.Run` or change the implementation of `_activeDirectory` to create the COM object it used to access the active directory inside the search method.

You also need to make sure, that the thread has the `ApartmentState` `ApartmentState.STA`. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16720496/set-apartmentstate-on-a-task) on how to do that.

---

The call to await immediately returns because of the exception. If an unhandled exception occurs within a task, the task is finished at that moment.

The search is executed and takes 5s when executed synchronously because the exception does not occur when using the COM object in the same thread as where it was created, as explained above.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this exception even after creating a new `UserModel` on the same thread as the Active Directory search.  The problem was that `IEnumerable<UserModel>` contained a nested type `UserPrincipal` which the main thread did not know about.  I was able to resolve this by using `.ToList()` which removed the nested type.

```
_context = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain);

public async Task<IEnumerable<UserModel>> SearchDisplayNameAsync(string searchPhrase, bool enabled = true)
{
    IEnumerable<UserModel> results = await Task.Run(() => SearchDisplayName(searchPhrase: searchPhrase, enabled: enabled));
    return results.ToList();  // <-- ToList() removes nested type
}

public IEnumerable<UserModel> SearchDisplayName(string searchPhrase, bool enabled = true)
{
    UserPrincipal userPrincipal = new UserPrincipal(_context)
    {
        DisplayName = $"{searchPhrase}*",
        Enabled = enabled
    };

    using (PrincipalSearcher searcher = new PrincipalSearcher(userPrincipal))
    {
        return searcher.FindAll()
            .OfType<UserPrincipal>()
            .Select(u => new UserModel
            {
                Guid = (Guid)u.Guid,
                DisplayName = u.DisplayName,
                EmailAddress = u.EmailAddress
            });
    }
}
```